# Linux distro to run a MIDI-server on a PII 333 MHz

Tags: distribution-choice, distributions, small-distribution, real-time, lightweight

I am looking for a Linux distro that can be used to redirect MIDI message from the network to the soundboard a TurtleBeach Montego from 1997. Currently the computer is running Windows 98 se and I get a total latency of 10 ms when feeding audio back through an analog cable. Since the computer has no display, I cannot do any remote control (other than shutdown, which I have added as ad-hoc messages).

Full hardware list:

- Sound: TurtleBeach Montego
- Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 6200 AGP
- CPU: Pentium II Deschutes 333 MHz
- RAM: 256 MB
- IDE controller

The following is a list of requirements for the setup

- A total latency shorter or equal to 10 ms
- SSH
- ALSA
- Utility programs (ls, cp, ... )

Also, it would be nice to achive digital audio return through "what you hear" port without increased latency (on Windows 98 I cannot come below 40 ms if I do so).

All distros seems to be too demanding for that machine. Do I need to configure my own? I do not need any GUI since it is just a server.

Comment: I'd suggest you check our Arch, it seems to meet your requirements.

Comment: Do you really have to use such an ancient ... uh ... <censored>?

Answer (score 2):

Latency is mostly a kernel issue, I'd say that newer kernels (and thus newer distributions) will give better results. Distributions are built on the same base software, so what should make a difference is probably more the familiarity with it (you *will* have to keep it up to date, and having a half-forgotten system around which is managed in an unfamiliar way is a sure recipe for bit rot). Check a minimal install for what you use day to day.

Answer (score 2):

[Planet CCRMA](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/software/). This is a Fedora-derived distribution optimized for audio. It includes optional realtime/low-latency patches for the kernel (see [this part of the docs for details](http://www-ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/software/installplaneteighteen.html#SECTION00020800000000000000)) but notes that recent kernels have a lot of this work integrated already and so you may actually find it good enough for your needs.

Within whichever distro you chose, you probably want to look at [JACK](http://jackaudio.org) for low-latency audio and MIDI.

Comment: For Fedora:

    A blank CD or DVD or a blank 1GB+ USB stick.
    A 400MHz or faster processor <= CPU is too slow
    1GB memory (RAM)             <= Need more RAM
    At least 10 GB hard drive space (only required for installation)

Is not JACK overkill?

Comment: The CPU difference is negligible. You're definitely pushing it for RAM; you'll have to use a text-mode install.

Comment: I looked at gentoo. It seems promising.

Answer (score 2):

Gentoo and some patience.

I've run Gentoo on more minimal hardware than that and was able to run a full X11 desktop with minimal WM and Opera Browser on it too. (it was more of an "I wonder if it would work" than a daily use box).

I'd recommend Gentoo and the following performance optimizations to limit CPU usage.

- Compile your kernel options manually selecting only the hardware you need.
- Compile specifically for the CPU with appropriate SSE extensions.
- Use BusyBox instead of the normal userland to further reduce memory & CPU loads
- compile the absolute minimum of the modular GPU drivers for X11 3 is usually the most you need. The one specifically for your card (ATI open source), the last resort VGA default, and whichever other fallback driver you prefer.
- Compile your audio kernel drivers to only provide the ones you need.
- Manually compile your userland software by carefully selecting the use flags, avoid any extraneous software that will touch the audio bus.

That may sound like a complex set of things, but to do all that on Gentoo will take just patience, a little medium level technical documentation reading, and determination to not throw in the towel.

Answer (score 0):

I use Debian (probably buster) on s plll 600 MHz with 256 MB ram as a streaming client. Works like a charm.